# The name control name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've gotten this popular error message, but deleting and re-adding the designer page doesn't help the issue.  When I created this web app I deleted the Masterpage (infrastructure) and copied the asp.net header from another non-site.master web app to this one.  I attempted to create a new web application, but everytime I do it comes with a Site.Master which I don't want.

So my question is two-pronged, is there a simple way to create a web-app without the site.master, just a simple aspx page, with a cs code-behind, or if I stick with the current web app, how do I clean it up so the controls on the page start existing in the current context?

Here is the header of the aspx page:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="VisionToPCC_XRef_Editor.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title>UltiPro to PolicyTech Import Utility</title> 
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Site.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/clientScripts.js"></script>
    <%--Old header:
    <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="VisionToPCC_XRef_Editor._Default" %>
    --%>
</head>
```

I noticed that the Inherits from the old header (see the bottom of the above snipet had an extra "_" in it, but adding this doesn't correct the problem.
I'm largely re-using code from another simple web app (that was created by someone else before my arrival here), so some of the "existence in this context" error messages are for actual controls which aren't in this new version, but the initial errors is for one that DOES exist. After I post this question I will go through and get rid of all the code in the code-behind that refers to non-existent controls...but here are a couple examples of controls from my aspx page if this helps your diagnoses:

```
            <div id="div_XRef_Type">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblChooser" runat="server"  Font-Bold="True" AutoPostBack="true"
                    Font-Size="Medium"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="rblChooser_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Payer Editor</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Facility Editor</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">ADT-ToFrom Editor</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </div>
            <div id="div_Messages" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_ErrorMessage" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Medium" Visible="false" 
                     runat="server" />
            </div>
```

I appreciate any non-"delete your designer file" help anyone can offer me.

Thanks,

EDIT:
Here is some of the code that is generating the errors (I'll put things with a red underline in all caps):

```
private void BindGridView_Payer()
        {
            bool booReturn = false;
            DataSet dsTable;
            string sErr = "";
            string sSQL = "";
        LBL_ERRORMESSAGE.Visible = false; //hide the error message if it's visible.

        try
        {
            if (RBLCHOOSER.SelectedValue.ToString() == "1")
            {
                DIV_PAYERGRID.Visible = true;
                DIV_FACILITYGRID.Visible = false;
                DIV_TOFROMGRID.Visible = false;
            }
```

It basically gives me an context error everytime I reference a control/div from that aspx page...thats why I didn't bother including the c# code...
Thanks.

Comment: You haven't really posted any relevant code. What code is throwing the error? What control are you trying to reach? What page is that control on - master or aspx?

Comment: I am none the wiser to what you want or what your issue is? You need to clarify your question and ask it more succinctly, have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @Liam I'm unsure how to be more succinct...I do tend to probably provide too much info but isn't more info better than not enough?  I've read the guide a couple times before.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I removed the master page.  The only two pages are Default.aspx and Default.aspx.cs

Comment: @BradAtCC `It basically gives me an context error everytime I reference a control/div from that aspx page` Your page is more than likely pointing at the wrong designer file... update the `inherits` to the correct location or don't copy the page directive from the old file.

Comment: @DGibbs ok, so the solution is called VisionToPCC_XREf_Editor and the Default.aspx page is on the root.  the code-behind and designer files are named: Default.aspx.cs and Default.aspx.designer.cs.  What should the inherits be in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is two-pronged, is there a simple way to create a web-app without the site.master, just a simple aspx page,

Yes:

- Click `New Project`
- Select `ASP.NET Empty Web Application`

Regarding the second problem

You have the `inherits` property pointing at the old designer file:

> Inherits="VisionToPCC_XRef_Editor.Default"

I suspect that pointing at the correct designer file will fix this. This also explains why deleting and then re-adding the designer does not fix the problem.

Comment: But, that is the correct solution name, and page name...any suggestions on how it should be different?  Solution is: VisionToPCC_XRef_Editor, webpage is Default.aspx, codebehind is Default.aspx.cs and Designer is: Default.aspx.designer.cs...

Comment: Look at your designer file, delete a control that is correctly referenced from it. Does it complain that the control can no longer be found? Try creating a brand new page and leave the page directive as-is, then copy the controls over one by one.

Comment: yea, starting over from scratch was the way to go...thanks for your help.